# git claiming files in repo are untracked

Tags: git

I've been working in a repo.. for years.  Suddenly today a whole set of files (basically whole directory structures within the project) are now 'untracked files'.  I have not modified any of the files. I've tried removing one and doing a git fetch to pull it back, to no avail.  My IDE can still see the files having a git history and all that, but the command line (and GitHub Desktop) see them as new files to be added to the repo.

I've tried hard reset and fetching and.. nothing.  Really driving me nutty in an already nutty time.

Comment: Have you tried to `git reset HEAD --hard`?

Comment: Yup!  Did that too.

Comment: *untracked* means *not in the index*. Why they are not there and not being put back there by `git reset --hard` is the mysterious part. If you're on Windows, it's probably a Windows thing: something has a lock on the index file and won't let Git update it.

Comment: Nope, a Mac.  Are the indexes kept at the root level or at each folder?  It was whole directories that 'went missing'... never just an individual file in a given directory.  Regardless, the reset should have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I have seemingly fixed it by removing the directories within the project that had gone bonkers and then doing a git reset HEAD --hard, followed by a git fetch.  Still not sure what went wrong, but I'll just chalk it up to covid-19.